# What is an abandoned buffer in vim?

Tags: buffers

I've been using vim for more than 5 years now, and I was surprised when I didn't know what an abandoned buffer was. The closest answer I found was in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15950622/1864317).

So is an abandoned buffer one that was loaded but is not displayed any more? What about if there are multiple tabs - are any of the buffers loaded in these tabs abandoned or not?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An "abandoned" buffer is a buffer you left without saving changes.

If you have `set nohidden` (the default value), Vim generally warns you about unsaved changes when you try to leave a modified buffer. When you force your way with a bang, the previous buffer becomes "abandoned" and you loose all your unsaved changes.

If you have `set hidden`, modified buffers are kept in their current state when you leave them so they are — technically — never "abandoned". You will still get a warning if you try to quit Vim with unsaved changes.

As long as it's still displayed in a window, a buffer can't be thought of as "hidden" or "abandoned" so your buffers currently displayed in another window in another tab page are neither "hidden" nor "abandoned".

Comment: I might have discovered a bug in this case (or just weird behaviour): 1. edit a buffer, don't save; 2. set hidden; 3. switch to another buffer; 4. set nohidden; 5. go back to hidden buffer; 6. go back to non-hidden buffer: the result is that the hidden buffer is automatically saved. Is this working as expected?

Comment: @stamm, can't reproduce

Comment: @stanm: can't reproduce either, after the 5. the first buffer is still changed but now I can't go back to the second buffer (because `nohidden` is set). What is your config ?

Comment: @Nobe4: okay, that's what I expected as behaviour. My config sources multiple external rc files (corp), so perhaps somewhere in there is the reason. Thanks for the help, though!

Comment: @stanm maybe `autowrite` gets involved? `set autowrite?` and `set autowriteall?`, what do they show?

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr: Yes! That was it. `autowrite` was set. Thanks!